# Downloading 10 images and storing their data with WWW

Tags: unity, textures, http

I would like to download 10 images, and store their texture data into my list. I don't really know how to do that - I heard that for this you use the WWW class, so I went:

```
List<byte[]> StartDownload() {
    List<byte[]> result = new List<byte[]> ();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        WWW request = new WWW("http://www.example.com/" + i + ".png");
        result.Add(request.texture);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Which of course doesn't work, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `yield` command so that unity will wait for the texture to download before subsequent code is executed.

[For Example.](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-texture.html)

```
// Get the latest webcam shot from outside "Friday's" in Times Square
var url = "http://images.earthcam.com/ec_metros/ourcams/fridays.jpg";
function Start () {
     // Start a download of the given URL
    var www : WWW = new WWW (url);
    // Wait for download to complete
    yield www;
    // assign texture
    renderer.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
}
```

Comment: Just a small note that in some cases polling [WWW.isDone](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-isDone.html) each frame can be useful.